# How to pass argument to TestNG listener

Tags: java, listener, testng

I have one TestNG file `demo.java` and one listener for it `DemoListener.java`

### `Demo.java`

```
import org.testng.*;
@Listeners(DemoListener.class)
public class Demo{
public static String testName = "DemoName" 

@Test(priority = 1)
public void demoTest() {
    Assert.assertEquals(some_value,value, "message");
  }
}
```

### `DemoListener.java`

```
import org.testng.ITestListener;
Public class DemoListener implements ITestListener {

@Override
public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult arg0) {
    System.out.println("On test Success:- ");
    // Here I want to access **variable(testName)** declared in Demo class.
    // Or is there anyway that I can pass that variable.
  }
}
```

Now, I want to access variable testName declared in Demo class in DemoListener class after every test execution. I would have declared it in DemoListener but I have so many class like Demo and each file has different testName.

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure why you're wanting to do this, perhaps a little background would be helpful.

But, to answer the question, you have a few options:

1. Define the variable in TestNG's XML. If you place it inside the properties construct, it will then be available to `System.getProperty()`.
2. Since `testName` is a public static, you can simply reference `Demo.testName` inside `DemoListener`.

I'm slightly confused why you can't simply use `ITestResult.getName()` though...

EDIT: For clarity, in your Demo.java, in each method, you can do the following:

```
ITestResult tr = Reporter.getCurrentTestResult();
tr.setName( "whatever name you want to give your test step" );
```

Then you can do the rest of your test (asserts etc). Later, in DemoListener.java, you're already passed an instance of ITestResult, and you can simply ask it for it's name (the one you set in the above code), by invoking `arg0.getName()`

Comment: I can't use #1 because I am not using testng.xml and also I can't use #2 because I have so many classes like Demo and DemoListener is common to them. Each class like Demo having different testName.

Comment: Perhaps you're misunderstanding my point.

In your Demo.java, you can set the name. I'll edit my answer now to demonstrate.

Comment: Thanks for answer :) and yeah, I misunderstood your point. Your answer is correct but I will have to add your code in every class. Check my answer. I don't have to edit existing class file, just listener class.

Comment: I figured reflection API was overkill for the purposes, but yes that's an option too. Watch out for a NullPointerException in cases where the field doesn't exist in your test class. (i.e. field variable in your answer may be null)

Answer (score 1):

Got answer of my question, used java reflection. Worked like charm.
I wrote following method in DemoListener class. Thanks to my friend Kailas!

```
public static void getTestSuiteName(ITestResult arg0){
 Class<?> clazz = arg0.getTestClass().getRealClass(); //Demo class
    Field field = null;
    try {
        field = clazz.getField("testSuiteName");
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    field.setAccessible(true);
    if(String.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())) {
        try {
            testSuiteName =  (String) field.get(null); //I can get value of testSuiteName set in Demo class
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```